# redux call reducer with action

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

This is my reducrer:

```
export default function dashboardReducer(state=initialState.alerts, action){
    switch(action.type){
        case constActions.GET_ALERTS_SUCCESS:
            return action.alerts;
        case constActions.GET_WL_STATISTICS_SUCCESS:
            return action.wlStatistics;
    default:
        return state;
    }
};
```

My root reducer:

```
const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    dashboard
});
```

In the component, this is the mapStateToProps:

```
function mapStateToProps(state, ownProps){
    return{
        alerts: state.dashboard
    };
}
```

Now I have 2 actions `GET_ALERTS_SUCCESS` and `GET_WL_STATISTICS_SUCCESS`.
In the component I have the props for `actions.alerts`, but how can I get a reference to `action.wlStatistics` in the component? can i call the reducer with an action type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your dashboardReducer either returns 'alerts' initialState OR 'alerts' OR 'wlStatistics' for the next state. It should return an object with both of those action payloads as properties:

```
const initialState = {
  alerts: null,
  wlStatistics: null
};

export default function dashboardReducer(state=initialState, action){
    switch(action.type){
        case constActions.GET_ALERTS_SUCCESS:
            return Object.assign({}, state, { action.alerts });
        case constActions.GET_WL_STATISTICS_SUCCESS:
            return Object.assign({}, state, { action.wlStatistics });
    default:
        return state;
    }
};
```

Your props will now be mapped as

```
this.props.alerts
```

and

```
this.props.wlStatistics
```

Whenever either action updates the state in the 'dashboardReducer', your component will re-render/receiveProps and the props will be updated with the new values